# Python subprocess causing issues with PowerShell CSV handling

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, subprocess, stdout

So really strange one here. I have a two-part script, one that does the data gathering in Python and the other that does all the AD stuff in PowerShell. Rather than having to run one and then the other I have used subprocess and stdout in Python to run the PowerShell script.

After further development, I realised that in certain situations I needed to change parts of the CSV file before handling it again for the final part in Python. Simple use `Export-Csv`, run it in PowerShell, no issues.

Run the script as a whole and if the CSV is edited by PowerShell via subprocess and stdout then for some strange reason PowerShell thinks there is an extra row in the CSV and tries to process it as a new user.

Again, if the code and same conditions are met and it is only run via PowerShell, no extra row occurs(have checked the file and all data looks as it should, no extra rows).

The offending lines of code are:

```
#Find out if its in use
while ($Exit -eq $false)
{
    $Return = UserExists $Username $Description

    if($Return -eq 'User does not exist')
    {
        $Exit = $true
        $Return = $Username
    }
    elseif($Return -eq 'User already exists')
    {
        $Exit = $true
    }
    elseif($Return -eq 'User does not exist but username does')
    {
        [STRING]$StringToAppend = $IntegerToAppend
        $UserName = $userinfo['username']+ $StringToAppend
        $sAMAccountName = $UserName
        [INT]$IntegerToAppend = [INT]$IntegerToAppend + 1

        $oldUN = $userinfo['username']
        $LC = $userinfo['learnerCode']

        $file = 'C:/XXX/XXX/XXXstudents.csv'
        $csv = Import-Csv $file

        foreach($row in $csv) 
        {
        if ($row.UserName -eq $oldUN -And $row.LearnerCode -eq $LC) {
        $row.UserName = $UserName
        $row.EmailAddress = $UserName + '@XXXXX.org.uk'
        }}
        $csv | Export-Csv  $file -NoTypeInformation;
    }
}
return $Return
}
```

The subprocess code is:

```
# Launch next part of script - Powershell create users
p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", 
              'C:/Provisioning/ProvisionStudents.ps1'], 
              stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

Now I feel as though the fact that the PowerShell script is editing the CSV file it is iterating over is something important and should be noted. However, I have this almost identical script doing the same for another site and it doesn't have this issue.

Any Ideas?

Comment: is there a reason NOT to use a different file for the changes? let each stage use a different file and the "stepping on itself" problem seems to vanish.

Comment: just seemed unnecessary to create an almost identical file when im only going to be changing 2 values per student and only if their username is already taken...ill go ahead and try with using a different file and see if the issue persists

Comment: also, just thought if changing the same file caused the issue would that not be the same for when only running it in PowerShell?

Comment: multithread access to a file is one of the classic "gotcha!" situations. [*grin*] you are strongly advised to NOT do that unless needed ... and then you are _very strongly_ recommended to use thread safe techniques to deal with the various gotchas that arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lee_Dailey has suggested exporting to a separate CSV file seems to do the trick, not sure why it only causes issues when run via subprocess though

If anyone cares to explain why this could be I would be eternally grateful